# DIY Single-Channel Television

Tags: lcd, tv

My building recently installed a CCTV camera system. Anyone with cable TV is able to tune into channel XX and watch the CCTV stream live.

I want to get a cheap and small LCD (≤7") and build a dedicated "television" that would be tuned to channel XX. Eventually, the plan is to hook this up to a caller-id circuit and have the "TV" turn on when I get a call from downstairs.

I'm a programmer by trade and don't have much experience with building circuits.
I'd just like a ballpark figure of what I'll need and how difficult it would be to make a primitive TV these days.

Comment: Are you asking "how do I set up this system (from phone line to LCD)?" or "how do I make a TV that is tuned to a single cable channel?"

Comment: @W5VO: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question. I'm asking the latter.

Comment: It's a little tricky because you probably have to decode the digital cable signal. Do you have a cable box already? If so, what connectors are on the back? If not, what choices do you have for cable providers?

Comment: @pingswept: there's no cable set-top box involved. It's simply coax to TV, so I guess it's just a traditional analogue signal.

Comment: The encoding for a cable signal is usually different than a terrestrial TV signal, though, so you'll need to make sure that the tuning unit can accept the cable signal.  In the USA, at least, you usually have to select ANT or CBL when setting up your TV to ensure it decodes the signal correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't the best first electronics project.  Decoding a cable TV feed isn't all that that complicated but its not overly easy either.

One approach is to use something like: [This for getting from baseband to the IF signal](http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/sn761678b.html)

That part is designed to be tuned over I2C with a microcontroller.

Sounds like you can ignore audio in your case which eases post processing, actually the IF signal can probably just go right into your little LCD screen, assuming it accepts an NTSC input.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. You're right on the audio end as well. I'm only interested in the picture.

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to buy a small handheld TV/ display that accepts NTSC, tune it to the channel (or hook it to a cable box / tuner tuned to the right channel), and then simply turn the power to it (or the video feed) on and off by some controller that handles the caller-id condition.

If your'e a programmer by trade, this is likely the easiest way to solve the problem, maximizing use of off-the-shelf parts.

Comment: I thought of that at first, but I'd like to get my feet wet with building some non-trivial circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Your camera probably has composite output which goes into some modulator box that encodes the signal to some specific TV channel. Intercept this signal before the box, and buy some cheap baby monitoring wireless camera system (actually you just need some home range CBSV to TV via air system). Every TV in the range will receive camera picture via air (including small 7" LCD if it is capable of receiving air TV signal). It can hardly get simpler then this.